# sed AndroidManifest for version

Tags: android, linux, sed

i've been banging my head against the wall, i need a sed one-liner to extract the versionName from an android manifest.
example below:

```
package="com.nosideracing.rchipremote"
android:versionCode="1014"
android:versionName="1.0.1.4" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'"' '/android:versionName/{print $(NF-1); exit}' manifestFile
```

**Note:** I haven't tested it. Replying via phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n '/android:versionName="/{;s///;s/".*$//;p;q;}' manifestFile
```

produces

```
1.0.1.4
```

Or did you want a concatenation of versionCode and versionName, OR ?

I hope this helps.

Comment: this works, but if there is leading whitespace, it prints that too, which is why i'm accepting the other answer

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^android:versionName="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p;d' manifestFile
1.0.1.4
```